# select isn't updating when using a component jsx react-js

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, react-hooks

I've got two select inputs that have a list of many countries. I put this list into one select component so I only needed to write one line in the parent component - like so

Child component:

```
const SelectCountry = props => {
 <select name={props.name} value={props.value} placeholder="Nationality".....>
   <option ...../>
   (etc.)
 </select>
}
```

Parent component:

```
<SelectCountry name={"nationalityA"} value={values.nationalityA} />
.....
.....
<SelectCountry name={"nationalityB"} value={values.nationalityB} />
```

This works fine except for when I make an API call and try to prepopulate the selects with the values returned from the API. For some reason, the values don't change in the SelectCountry component if I set the values for nationalityA and nationalityB as what was returned from the API. If I add the following into the parent component however the value from the API call displays:

```
<select name="nationalityA" value={values.nationalityA} placeholder="Nationality".....>
   <option ...../>
   (etc.)
 </select>

.....

<select name="nationalityB" value={values.nationalityB} placeholder="Nationality".....>
   <option ...../>
   (etc.)
 </select>
```

For the API call itself, I am making it within a custom UseForm hook and then setValues({}) in there so the input fields are prepopulated

I wanted to keep the code clean so would rather the select country was in one component. What do I need to do?

Comment: did u try to add `selected` attr to option instead?

Comment: @demkovych the issue with this (I think) is that I need to put selected and disabled on the placeholder so I can't put it onto another option